# Share Component between 2 modules

Tags: angular

I'm trying to include a `Component` in 2 modules (parent and child) but getting various errors in the process

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [SharedComponent],
    exports: [SharedComponent]...
})
```

**child.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedComponent], //Unexpected directive imported by module
})
```

**app.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <shared-selector></shared-selector>
    <child-selector></child-selector>
</div>
```

**child.html**

```
<div>
    content
    <shared-selector></shared-selector>
</div>
```

I'm loading the *ChildModule* in Async matter

```
loadChildren: 'app/child.module#ChildModule',
```

When not `importing` or `declaring` in the `ChildModule` I'm getting the error:

```
template parse error: shared-selector is not a known element
```

****** **UPDATE** *******

when Creating `FeatureModule`, in order to work the `SharedModule` should export the Components...updateed code...

**SharedModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
     ],
    declarations: [
         SharedComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        SharedComponent
    ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ChildModule, SharedModule],...
})
```

**child.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule], //Unexpected directive imported by module
})
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**update**

`imports` is only for modules, not components. 
I doubt it will work out if the `app.module` exports the shared component. Make it a `SharedModule` or `MyFeatureModule` instead and add this module to `imports` where you want to use the elements the module exports.

**original**

One component can only be added `declarations` of exactly one `@NgModule()`

As workaround create a new module for the component and add the new module to `imports: [...]` of the other two modules (where you want to use it).

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11481#issuecomment-246186173

> When you make a component part of a module you impart on it a set of rules when it is compiled. Having a component without belonging to a NgModule is meaningless as the compiler can't compile it. Having a component be part of more then one module is also weird as you are saying that depending which module you chose the rules for compiling are different. And when you dynamically load such a component it would be ambiguous which set of compilation rules you wanted.
>
> The idea of removing that each component belongs to exactly one module is a no-go for the reasons stated above.

Comment: I understand this fact. what i don't understand why it's not working if i 'exported' it in the parent module, and imported it on the Childmodule

Comment: `imports` is only for modules, not components and it's `imports` not `imported`. I doubt it will work out if the `app.module` exports the shared component. Make it a `SharedModule` or `MyFeatureModule` instead.

Comment: Add `exports: [SharedComponent]` to `SharedModule`.

Comment: And in `ChildModule` import the **module** not the component `imports: [SharedModule], `

Comment: `exports` did the trick...the SharedComponenet was just a typo...Thanks!

Answer (score 134):

For completeness, according to Gunter's answer, use a `SharedModule`:

**SharedModule**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
     ],
    declarations: [
        SharedComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        SharedComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [ChildModule, SharedModule],...
})
```

**child.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule]
})
```

Comment: Why would I want to add the SharedModule to app.module when I have to add the SharedModule to childmodules? (It works without adding SharedModule in app.module)

Comment: Shared module can only be used in the `ChildModule`(A single level), and in order to use the `SharedModule` in ` a grand child module` you have to import it (the `SharedModule`) in the `ChildModule`.

Comment: That is the correct solution, should be mark like the good answer also. Sorry but I barely understand the sentences in the answered solution "One component can only be added declarations of exactly one @NgModule()"???...

Comment: Would anything in this answer change if the shared module was lazy loaded? I assume that if this module was used in ModuleX-Lazy then the shared module would load when ModuleX-Lazy loads. But if the shared module was also used in ModuleY-NotLazy, then it loads at startup. This sounds right to me,can someone confirm please?

Comment: +1 for showing the `exports: []` on the shared module. It was missing in my code for which I was getting error.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - agree should be marked as answer as clearer solution to problem.  Been hunting for a few days for this!

Comment: 'An example is worth a thousand words '

Answer (score 15):

Create a SharedModule. Declare and export the SharedComponent.

shared.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { SharedComponent } from './shared';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     SharedComponent
   ],
   imports: [
     CommonModule
   ],
   exports: [
     SharedComponent
   ],
   providers: [

   ]
 })
 export class SharedModule { }
```

Import SharedModule in AppModule and any other Modules.

app.module.ts

```
  import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      SharedModule
    ]
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include the shared component in your providers: section of SharedModule.
Then from derived module, you just import SharedModule, and Bingo.

```
    import { PagingInfoComponent } from './paging/paging.component';

   @NgModule({
      providers: [ PagingInfoComponent ],
      declarations: [ ],
      exports: [ ]
    })

   export class SharedModule {}
```

And, in your derived module,

```
import { SharedModule } from '../location/to/shared.module';
@NgModule({
 imports: [SharedModule ]
});
```

Comment: Completely wrong, providers is for injecting dependency. read more here about providers https://angular.io/guide/providers