# Clicking link triggers "Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined' "

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-cli, angular7

I have an app that I am trying to build using lazyloading, since there are a lot of nested paths. This app will also be predominantly mobile, so improving that experience is critical.

The instance I have set up is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsfvdr

I thought most of it was set up correctly, but when clicking on a link in the main page, I get this error stack trace:

```
preview-ee4d58d6ef0576b4e139b.js:formatted:7278 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in 
promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
  Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
     at NgModuleResolver.resolve (ng_module_resolver.ts:31)
     at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (metadata_resolver.ts:506)
     at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.ts:127)
     at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.ts:107)
     at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.ts:61)
```

My first thought was that there was either a module incorrectly defined, or a component was being incorrectly loaded as a module. I am pretty new to angular, so every curveball is a learning experience! But I am stumped here.

Click the link above to view the Stack Blitz project example.

Comment: I suggest you to read the [Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) in Angular. There are many errors in your example project.

Comment: there are multiple issues with your code but the error above is solved by adding the modules classname to your lazy Module routing config's `loadChildren`

like `loadChildren: './pages/hello/hello-pages.module#HelloPagesModule'` in `app.routing.module.ts`

Comment: There were quite a few issues with the stackblitz.  I've forked and fixed the stackblitz.  Hopefully this is somewhat helpful.  Most of the changes were in the routing files and the module files for app, hello, and goodbye. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rachgj

Comment: look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrxa6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I fixed the issues (and added a router-outlet, so the hello-component is rendered)

Comment: thanks guys! this helps a lot. Like I said, totally new to this. Like 3 days in

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not about routes only, but let's do it step by step:

> 1. `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/hello' }`, `redirectTo` doesn't require trailing slash,

**replace by** `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'hello' }`

> 2. for lazy loading definition you forgot a module name

*app.routing.module.ts*

```
loadChildren: './pages/hello/hello-pages.module'
loadChildren: './pages/goodbye/goodbye-pages.module'
```

**replace by**

```
loadChildren: './pages/hello/hello-pages.module#HelloPagesModule'
```

but for `goodbye-pages.module` you copy-pasted `HelloPagesModule`, suppose it should be `GoodByePagesModule`

```
loadChildren: './pages/goodbye/goodbye-pages.module#GoodByePagesModule'
```

> 3. don't know why you import `GoodbyeRoutes` into `goodbye-pages.module.ts` and then override it, seems again - wrong copy-pasting

**replace by** `//import { GoodbyeRoutes } from '../routes/goodbye.routing.module';`

> 4. `loadChildren: '../routes/goodbye.routing.module#GoodbyeRoutingModule'` - wrong path

**replace by** `loadChildren: '../../routes/goodbye.routing.module#GoodbyeRoutingModule'`

> 5. if you are using `component` with  `loadChildren` ex:
>      *app.routing.module.ts*

```
{
    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Hello pieces'
    },
    loadChildren: './pages/hello/hello-pages.module#HelloPagesModule'
},
```

`HelloComponent` should be `declared` in `AddModule` (its ok), but I suppose you've mixed declaration in routes and `HelloComponent` same as `GoodbyeComponent` should be used within their modules

so no need to use `component: HelloComponent,` and `component: GoodbyeComponent,` inside *app.routing.module.ts*

**AND** NgModule import [should be used for modules only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486147/4483102)

so this *app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, GoodbyeComponent ],
  exports: [HelloComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

**replace by**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

and then *hello-pages.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(HelloRoutes), CommonModule, FormsModule, HelloComponent],
    declarations: [GloryhammerComponent, SabatonComponent, SweetComponent],
    exports: []
})
```

**replaced by**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(HelloRoutes), CommonModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [HelloComponent, SabatonComponent, SweetComponent],
    exports: []
})
```

> 6. To make routing works:

you have to add [`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet) inside your `app.component.html`

> 7. After **point 6** app will work (but not at all), to finalize it you should fix also 'lazy' routes, so based on **point 5**

*hello.routing.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(LazyHelloRoutes), CommonModule, HelloComponent],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [HelloComponent]
})
```

**replace by**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(LazyHelloRoutes), CommonModule, HelloPagesModule],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
```

and *goodbye.routing.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(LazyGoodbyeRoutes), CommonModule, GoodbyeComponent],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [GoodbyeComponent]
})
```

**replace by**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(GoodbyeRoutes), CommonModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [GoodbyeComponent, LouComponent, DijouComponent, HermesComponent],
    exports: [GoodbyeComponent]
})
```

after all of these steps, all will work as expected

Modified <kbd>[**Demo**](https://angular-hhosd2.stackblitz.io)</kbd>