# Keep getting Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'component' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular-components

Here are some code fragments.

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-generalstatistics',
 templateUrl: './generalstatistics.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./generalstatistics.component.css']
})
export class Generalstatistics  {
 public data: Array<Object>;
 constructor() { }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Generalstatistics } from './views/generalstatistics/generalstatistics.component';

   declarations: [
   ....
   Generalstatistics
],
```

Implementation in DashboardModule/DashboardComponent.html:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper mt-3 mx-3" style="height:70px;">
      <app-generalstatistics></app-generalstatistics>
    </div>
```

Error:

```
core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-generalstatistics' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-generalstatistics' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-generalstatistics' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    </div>
    <div class="chart-wrapper mt-3 mx-3" style="height:70px;">
      [ERROR ->]<app-generalstatistics></app-generalstatistics>
    </div>
  </div>
 "): ng:///DashboardModule/DashboardComponent.html
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I assume you should add the `app-generalstatistics` component to the `declaration: []` of your `DashboardModule` too. The NgModule is the compilation context for the templates afaik, so we have to declare a component in every module in which it is used. Otherwise compilation would probably take a while because in that case Angular would have to go searching for the component. And it could possibly in any dependency including 3rd parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you should add the `app-generalstatistics` component to the `declarations: []` of your `DashboardModule` as well (Actually just where you use it)

Afaik the NgModule is the compilation context for the templates. 
So we have to declare a component in every module in which it is used.

Why? In my thinking: Otherwise the compilation would probably take a while because in that case Angular would have to go searching for the components definition and that could possibly be in any dependency including 3rd parties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a component from a parent module. In this case, the AppModule is the parent and DashboardModule is a child module. Instead, I suggest creating a SharedModule where your Generalstatistics component lives, like this:

**shared.module.ts**

```ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [Generalstatistics],
    exports: [Generalstatistics]
})
export class SharedModule;
```

Your `Generalstatistics` component would be in `./app/shared/` instead of the root `./app`.

Import `SharedModule` in DashboardModule:

**dashboard.module.ts**

```ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    ...
})
export class DashboardModule;
```

You'd also import SharedModule in any other module that would want to use the `Generalstatistics` component.

Here is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486147/12431728) to another question.

Comment: I have a views folder where there are two subfolders. In one subfolder I have DashboardModule module. That's where I am trying to implement generalstatistics component, That lives lives in the other subfolder. So, not sure about creating a shared module.

Comment: @Mark I think you'd create another subfolder for a SharedModule, then you would import that into the DashboardModule in the imports, like I mentioned in my answer. You can't simply import a component by its path. The component has to be exported by its containing module, then that module has to be imported in another module where you want to use the component.

Comment: I think I just made it work. I moved relevant to Generalstatictics code from app module to DashboardModule and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this  `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` in your module, why because is required to use **custom HTML tags**

Comment: Can you please explain why? And what module, app?

Comment: @Mark hope useful

Comment: Adding schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] to app module didn't hep.