# How to handle "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'alert' is not a known element:" in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am developing an authentiaction app in AngularJS. There I want to print an alert message if the username or password is incorrect. Below is my implementation,

alert.component.html :-

```
<div *ngIf="message" [ngClass]="message.cssClass">{{message.text}}</div>
```

alert.module.ts :-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AlertComponent } from './alert.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [AlertComponent],
    exports: [AlertComponent]
})
export class AlertModule {}
```

login.component.html :-

```
<sb-layout-auth>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="card shadow-lg border-0 rounded-lg mt-5">
                    <div class="card-header"><h3 class="text-center font-weight-light my-4">Login</h3></div>
                    <alert></alert>   //<---------------------- Here I want call the alert
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
                            <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" for="inputEmailAddress">Email</label><input formControlName="userName" class="form-control py-4" id="inputEmailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Enter email address" /></div>
                            <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" for="inputPassword">Password</label><input formControlName="password" class="form-control py-4" id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Enter password" /></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"><input class="custom-control-input" id="rememberPasswordCheck" type="checkbox" /><label class="custom-control-label" for="rememberPasswordCheck">Remember password</label></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-4 mb-0"><a class="small" routerLink="/auth/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a><button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary" >Login</button></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <div class="small"><a routerLink="/auth/register">Need an account? Sign up!</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</sb-layout-auth>
```

login.module.ts :-

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from '../../../../app/app-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

import { AlertModule } from '../../components/alert.module'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LoginComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, AlertModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

I implemented the alert functionality referring to [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/07/05/angular-8-alert-toaster-notifications) example. It is working when I add the `<alert></alert>` tag to the **app.component.html** and **login.module.ts** was implemented on my own by referring it.But I want to add it to the login component and once I add the `<alert></alert>` tag in the **login.component.html** the error occurs. Since I am new to angular, I can't figure out where I am doing wrong. Can you please help me! Thanks for the time.

-------------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------------

Error :-

```
core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<sb-layout-auth>
    <div class="container">
        [ERROR ->]<alert></alert>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
"): ng:///AuthModule/LoginComponent.html@2:8
Error: Template parse errors:
'alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<sb-layout-auth>
    <div class="container">
        [ERROR ->]<alert></alert>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
"): ng:///AuthModule/LoginComponent.html@2:8
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2281)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11693)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26863)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26851)
    at compiler.js:26795
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26795)
    at compiler.js:26708
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2272)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26707)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41333)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

Comment: Can you please put the error as well ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error. Can you please check it? Thanks @RajatMishra

Comment: Have you defined the selector for alert component?

Comment: I have added this line in alert.component.ts - ```@Component({ selector: 'alert', templateUrl: 'alert.component.html' })```
@huanfeng

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038690/keep-getting-uncaught-in-promise-error-template-parse-errors-component-is if this helps..Looks like you need the add the component in declarations

Comment: Import `AlertModule` in `AuthModule`