# Showing component passed by parameter

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to create a component that receives as parameter another component an wrap it in a NgBootstrap modal but adding some html elements.

I dont know if this is possible, the main reason I want to do this is for adding header and footer to modals that have the same function(like close button, accept and cancel), and the only thing that changes is the body, which should show the component passed as parameter.

Any idea of how can I solve this?

Comment: look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486029/share-component-between-2-modules

Comment: thanks, but it's not what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `<ng-content>` the example below is a modal generic template where `modalTitle` is a parameter

**html**

```
    <!-- modal header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>

   <!-- modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
    })
    export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() modalTitle: string;

      constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

      closeModal() {
        this.activeModal.close();
      }

    }
```

so when you want to use your modal dynamically you should wrap the code above in a component and "extend it" like this

```
<app-modal modalTitle="this is my title">
    <!-- start of dynamic content-->
    <div>
       <h2>This is my dynamic content</h2>
       <p>I'am extending modal template...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end of dynamic content -->
<app-modal>
```